# Symfony 1.4 doctrine:data-dump reserverd words

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, data-dump

I have a table with 2 columns with reserved words (`read`, `write`), while yes I can change the column names I want to see if there is a way to do things as is, for educational purposes :-)

When I load these tables and build my models there is no issue, Symfony has no issue reading the tables from my YAML file, however when I try a data dump the SQL freaks out because read/write are reserved words, YES they are being put into `read` ticks appropriately, but still no love.

So my question is, is their an option to use escape chars or some other option to give data-dump to account for these special chars, OR Is there a way to exclude a table from the data-dump?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Just pick different words man.

Comment: Tom! Doing things the easy way will never get you anywhere! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to use *quote_identifier: true*

```
doctrine:
  class: sfDoctrineDatabase
  param:
    dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbname
    username: root
    password: mysecret
    attributes:
      quote_identifier: true
      default_table_collate: utf8_general_ci
      default_table_charset: utf8
```